# Left mouse press program in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written a program for detect left mouse press. But it execute too fast and print the output with taking input from mouse. If i hold the left mouse key and then execute, Then it print "Pressed". How can i make this program to wait for mouse press and then show output.

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data
msg1 db "Clicked$"
msg2 db "Not Cllicked$"
var1 db 0
.code   
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
    mov ax, 13h
int 10h
call SetCursor ; mouse input


cmp bx, 01 ; check if left mouse was clicked
je L1
lea dx,msg2
mov ah,9
int 21h

L1:
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,9
int 21h

;Exit Graphic mode
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
 mov ah,4ch
 int 21h 
MAIN ENDP
SetCursor proc 

;initialize the mouse
mov ah,01
int 33h
 mov ax, 0h

 int 33h

 ;show mouse
 

 mov ax, 1h

 int 33h

; get mouse place and status

mov ax, 3h

int 33h

ret

SetCursor endp 
END MAIN
```

Comment: _"If i hold the left mouse key and then execute, Then it print "Pressed"."_ I assume that you mean `"Clicked"`. In any case, it's not entirely clear from your question exactly under what conditions you want to print `"Clicked"` or `"Not Clicked"`. You can write a loop that repeatedly get the mouse status until the relevant bit becomes 0, and then again until it becomes 1. But then you'll never end up in the `"Not Clicked"` case, unless you add some sort of timeout.

Comment: I just want to use mouse left click for a project. I want it will return a status to me when left mouse key is Clicked. Such as it return a status for keyboard keys.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cmp bx, 01 ; check if left mouse was clicked
> je L1
> lea dx,msg2
> mov ah,9
> int 21h
>
> L1:
> lea dx,msg1
> mov ah,9
> int 21h
> ```

You need to take care with constructs like these! Your code will always print *msg1* even if you only needed *msg2*. This happens because you allow the code to fall through from the above printout into the below printout. You need to insert a by-passing jump here:

```
 lea dx,msg2
 mov ah,9
 int 21h
 jmp L2        <<<< the by-pass
L1:
 lea dx,msg1
 mov ah,9
 int 21h
L2:
```

---

Your program "executes too fast" because you only test the mouse condition once, and then immediately exit the program. You need to check the button status in a loop that continually updates the screen with a suitable message and that terminates the program only after pressing some keyboard key.

Next program works that way:

```
.model small
.stack 100

.data
msg1 db "Left Button Down", 13, "$"
msg2 db "Left Button Up  ", 13, "$"

.code   
MAIN PROC
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax
  mov ax, 0013h  ; Set video mode 19 (320x200)
  int 10h
  mov ax, 0000h  ; Initialize the mouse
  int 33h        ; -> AX BX
  mov ax, 0001h  ; Show mouse arrow
  int 33h

MainLoop:
  mov  ax, 0003h ; Get mouse info
  int  33h       ; -> BX CX DX
  lea  dx, msg2  ; The "Not clicked" message
  test bx, 1     ; Test left mouse button
  jz   Up
Down:
  lea  dx, msg1  ; The "Clicked" message
Up:
  mov  ah, 09h   ; Print string
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 01h   ; Test keyboard
  int  16h       ; -> AX ZF
  jz   MainLoop  ; No key is waiting
  mov  ah, 00h   ; Fetch key
  int  16h       ; -> AX

  mov  ax, 0003h ; Set video mode 3 (80x25)
  int  10h
  mov  ax, 4C00h ; Terminate program
  int  21h
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```